# Does editing a post make it more 'visible' on the list of questions?

Tags: support

The single answer I received to a question led me to understand how I really wanted to ask the question and to be more specific.

I've edited and expanded my question, but by now, the bulk of users looking at new questions have already viewed it, and only saw the old version of my question.

Do large edits 'bump' the question nearer to the top of the pile, so to speak, so that it will be viewed again?

Comment: *All* edits bump the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Editing cause something known as "bump", and updates the last activity time of the question.

Most users browse the list of questions sorted by last activity, which is the default sort, so they will see the question again.